# Versioning with Visual Source Safe without Visual Studio

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-sourcesafe

I have some reports developed using Crystal Reports 12 and I want to version it using Visual Source Safe but I don't use Visual Studio. Is there a way I can do this without VS or do I have to install VS in order to version my CR reports?

Comment: You want to use Visual Source Safe, but you want to avoid Visual Studio?  I suspect that this question is most definitely *not* a duplicate.

Comment: There are other source control products out there, and Visual Source Safe has a less-than-stellar reputation... any reason why you specifically want VSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing the [Visual Sourcesafe client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181051%28VS.80%29.aspx)  should be sufficient.

You might want to check out (no pun intended) other Source Controls. We have been using Visual Sourcesafe for several years without any hickups but it is not considered the most performant or even trusthworthy Source Control solution.

---

Some well respected open source Source Controls that come to mind

**VCS**

- [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/)

**DVCS**

- [git](http://git-scm.com/)
- [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Lieven. Here at the company we cannot use versioners like svn because of some politics, we can't use svn because it's free and there's not maintenance contract with the developers.  Sad but true... =/

Comment: If they insist on paying for a sourcecontrol, Microsoft Team Foundation Server offers source control and should be faster and much more reliable. We will be switching to TFS this year. That being said, perhaps it is allowed for you to have git or mercurial installed on your own development machine. That is what I've done.